# Python - Count frequency of matching value in each row

Tags: python, pandas, rows, frequency, countif

I have a dataframe (df1) with training items (157) in rows  and users (65) as columns, e.g:

```
                User1           User2         User3           User4     
Training1       Qualified       Qualified     Not Qualified   Qualified
Training2       Not Qualified   Qualified     Qualified       Not Qualified
```

I want to add 2 columns for 'Qualified' and 'Not Qualified' that counts the number of each occurance per training item (row).

So the result above would have 3 'Qualified and 1 'Not Qualified' for 'Training1' etc.

I have tried the following code:

```
dff = df1.copy()
dff['Qualified']=(df1 == 'Qualified').T.count()
dff['Not Qualified']=(df1 == 'Not Qualified').T.count()
```

However, this just gives me a count of 65 for every row.

Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need `sum` on `axis=1`: `(df1 == 'Qualified').sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you! Always something easy.  However, I am now not getting the correct value, I think because of the formatting from my csv....'Qualified\r\n' is in my original df so I used:
#df1 = df1.replace('\n',' ', regex=True)
#df1 = df1.replace('\r',' ', regex=True)
It looks correct on my df but think there must be a formatting issue as the sum() is showing as zero.  Thank you again

Comment: yes i think it should be a formatting issue.